# revert back the branch

Tags: git, github, git-cherry-pick

I have a **master** branch and a **feature** branch.

I have some commits in **feature** branch, and I `cherry-pick`ed them to **master** branch.

So, now my **master** branch contains those commits already. I noticed then I shouldn't do those `cherry-pick`s.

Now, how can I revert my **master** branch back to the status before cherry-pick?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't push the bad changes to remote yet:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <commit_before_bad_changes>
```

If you did push the bad changes to remote already:

```
git checkout master
git revert <bad_commit_1>
git revert <bad_commit_2>
git revert <bad_commit_3>
```

Revert will not remove the bad commits from the history but create new commits which remove the content of the bad commits.

Comment: the reverts should be in reverse order (revert the last one first) to avoid conflicts; `git reset --hard origin/master` is IMO preferable (same as your first suggestion, just likely easier to understand/remember).